Completely positive maps on the norm closure of an operator system
Definition. Let $A$ be a unital C*-algebra. If $A$ has a unit $1$ and $S$ is a self-adjoint ($S^*=S$) subsapce of $A$ containing $1$, then we call $S$ an $operator$ $system$.
Question: Let $S$ be an operator system, $B$ be a C*-algebra, and $\phi: S\rightarrow B$ be a completely positive map. How to prove (if it is true) that $\phi$ extends to a completely positive map on the norm closure of $S$?
An exercise from Page 21 of the book Completely Bounded Maps and Operator Theory by V. Paulsen answers this question when we wish to have positivity (not complete positivity).

$\overline{\phi} \otimes 1_{M_n} = \overline{\phi \otimes 1_{M_n}}$, where the overline denotes the (unique continuous) extension of a map to the norm closure of its domain. From there it is obvious the result for positivity implies the result for complete positivity.

If $\phi:S\to B$ is a completely positive map the for any natural number $n$ the map, $\phi^{(n)}:M_n(S)\to M_n(B)$ is a positive map.
Now note that $M_n(S)$ is a subspace of $M_n(A)≈M_n\otimes A$. Show that $\bar{M_n(S)}$ taken inside $M_n(A)$ is $M_n(\bar{S})$.
To show that you need to know that the minimal tensor norm convergence on $M_n\otimes A$ is same as entrywise norm convergence on $M_n(A)$. Now use the exercise you have mentioned to prove this.
